# How to remove a blank space on an element?

Tags: css, alignment, text-alignment

I have a `h2 tag` but the text isn't aligned with the left of the element as you can see on the picture.

Is it possible to remove this blank space or stick the text to the left?

[image: Blank space on left]

Here are the CSS attributes:

```
h2 {
   font-size: 5.2em;
   font-family: UniSans;
   word-spacing: 1px;
}
```

:** Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LB2N5/1/) with my problem. And if there is a solution for the top blank space it would be great.

Comment: You may have a padding on the container, or a margin on your h2. Share a jsfiddle it will be easier to see the problem

Comment: @thomash you are talking about space when selecting the text?

Comment: The picture represents a hover on chrome's console but the problem seems to happen with a selection too. The fact is my element isn't correctly aligned because of this blank.

Comment: thats actually a font behavior.. If you will use another font family you will see different result.

Comment: @KheemaPandey You're right, with the basic font the text is correctly aligned !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is standard behaviour for sans-serif fonts I believe. The glyph has extra 'room' around it for ascender/decenders/serifs AFAIK.

[Codepen.io example](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/fCdsl)

**HTML**

```
<h1>Decent Test</h1>

<h1 class="serif" >Decent Test</h1>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 100px;
  font-family:sans-serif;
  word-spacing: 1px;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  background: pink;
  margin: 50px;
}

h1.serif {
  font-family: serif;  
}
```

Comment: Actually, the blank comes from my font :/

Answer (score 0):

Update your CSS like below. Hopefully it will fix the issue.

```
body, html{margin:0; padding:0} 
h2 {
font-size: 5.2em;
font-family: UniSans;
word-spacing: 1px;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LB2N5/7/)

Comment: Updated my answer. check it out. You missed to set `padding:0; margin:0;` on body.

Comment: It's the same problem as @singe31. If I add a border, the text won't be stick to it.

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai its a basically font related issues. By choosing the other font family OP might get bigger space or space could be reduced

Comment: agree with @Kheema Pandey

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `margin:0` to your `body` and to your `h2`

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/LB2N5/3/

Comment: If I change the font-size to 5em, there is a blank between the border and the text. I don't want to :/

Comment: This is the size of the letter, you can't do much about that, except relative positionning but it depends on the font size so you'll have to add `position:relative` and `left:-5px` for example or whatever value is good to you.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to make the margin negative on your  element like with -2px, you can adjust it to your Situation.